# Is it possible to install my App on my test IPhone

Tags: ios, xamarin, certificate

Maybe that's a stupid question, but I've updated my app and I want to upload it to the App Store.

Unfortunately I can no longer run my app, which I marked with the Profile Distributed, on my test IPhone before uploading the app to the store.

Unfortunately I could find no indication with Apple, that this had changed that. It always used to be.

Does anyone have a hint?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Off course you can run it , the app is signed with a development and distribution certificates not only the distribution , so make sure you set the correct settings for the app , then run it

Another option is to use testflight , add yourself as test user , then install testflight app from AppStore , after the app finish processing it should appear , before you release it

A tip : for any unexpected problems make always the distribution after submitting for review manually so you can decide whether to release that version or not after a successful review

Comment: is it signed with both development and distribution? When i signe it with development, it is no problem to install and run the app on the Iphone. Only when i sign it with distribution, then the message appear => "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found"

I uploaded the api file to the app store, and apple approved everthing, but I'm not shure if it workes. That's why I do not want to share the app...

Comment: You can only run apps that you have signed for development.  Apps signed for distribution are sent to Apple and you can run it once Apple re-signs it and you install it from the App Store

Comment: ah ok, but this is new. 2 weeks ago it worked! I could publish my app which was signed with distribution on my iphone...

Comment: the signing process includes both at the same time ,  to test what already sent use testflight , btw i think testing the same unchanged code in development and distribution won't make any difference